# Don't allow users to create nodes until they have at least one comment

Tags: rules

I'm trying to create a community website using drupal where users can create accounts, login and create nodes but i don't want them to create a node until they have at least one comment on a node. I heard rules will be able to accomplish this but I don't know hw to set it to disallow users from creating a node until they have a content

Answer (score 5):

You can do this is with the [Rules](http://drupal.org/project/rules) module.

1. Remove the permission to create nodes from authenticated users.
2. Create a new role (e.g., one_comment) and give this role the permission to create nodes.
3. Create a rule that is triggered when a comment is posted and gives the user who posted the comment the one_comment role.